# A list file to an numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a file named "abc.data", which containes element in the form as

39, State-gov, 77516, Bachelors, 13, Never-married, Adm-clerical, Not-in-family, White, Male, 2174, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K
50, Self-emp-not-inc, 83311, Bachelors, 13, Married-civ-spouse, Exec-managerial, Husband, White, Male, 0, 0, 13, United-States, <=50K

I want to make an array to store the above data , also is it possible to store the all the elements in the X[] except the last element , and last element in Y[] like,

X=[39, State-gov, 77516, Bachelors, 13, Never-married, Adm-clerical, Not-in-family, White, Male, 2174, 0, 40, United-States]
Y=[<=50K]

Comment: Question is about `numpy`, and it has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (edited).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on @kabooya 's answer above: although the suggestion works, it produces lists X and Y instead of numpy arrays as asked in the question. Plus, I imagine you have multiple lines in the file, so you could loop through them to create a list of records as:

```
import numpy as np
path_to_file = './abc.data' # insert your path here
X_list = []
Y_list = []
with open(path_to_file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f: #line = f.readline()
        features_list = [el.strip() for el in line.split(',')]
        # target_dict = {'Y': features_list[-1].strip()}
        # for idx_record in range(len())
        X = np.array(features_list[:-1])
        Y = np.array([features_list[-1]])
        X_list.append(X)
        Y_list.append(Y)
```

where the strip() is used to clean the strings from trailing and leading white spaces.

Comment: thnx , thats exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
with open('abc.data') as file:
    out = file.read()
    out = out.split(',')
    X = out[:-1]
    Y = [out[-1]]
    
    print(X, Y)
```

Read the file, split the file at comma's (forming an array), place every element but last in X array, last element in Y array